# Calculos errados con number_format()

Tags: php

Al ejecutar este código:

```
$valor_base=495.45;
$valor_mul=0.25;
$porcen=0.80;
$mul=2;

$res=$valor_base*$valor_mul;
$res+=($mul==2) ? number_format($res*0.80) : 0.00;
echo $res;
```

Esto en teoría me debería dar 222,95 pero en cambio me da 222.86
Porque sucede esto?

Comment: Documentación de PHP: [number_format](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.number-format.php) sin segundo argumento elimina los decimales. Además esa instrucción debe usarse para mostrar datos, no para hacer cálculos intermedios, ya que inserta otros caracteres (`,` o `.`) a la cadena resultante.

Comment: Hola, eso es lo que deseo que me de un formato de dinero 000,000.00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descompongamos tu operación

```
$valor_base=495.45;
$valor_mul=0.25;
$porcen=0.80;
$mul=2;
```

```
$res=$valor_base*$valor_mul; // = 123.8625
```

```
number_format($res*0.80) // = 99
```

---

```
$res+=($mul==2) ? number_format($res*0.80) : 0.00;
```

Esto es lo mismo que:

```
$res = 123.8625 + 99; // = 222.8625
```

---

Lo que sospecho intentas haces es:

```
$res = ($mul==2) ? number_format($res*0.80+$res,2) : number_format($res,2); //222.95
```

Lo que te falta es agregar el segundo parámetro en [number_format](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.number-format.php), el cual te indica la cantidad de decimales, en caso contrario te deja el número sin decimales

Comment: Gracias, para operaciones con formato de dinero es recomendable usar number_format?

Comment: Es decir cuando se ejecuten operaciones matemáticas basadas en dinero no afecta el uso de esta función? claro agregándole el segundo parámetro de corte de decimales(2)

Comment: Para los casos de dinero dependerá de las leyes de cada país. En el mío se debe aproximar siempre al más cercano, y al final de la operación. Esto último es importante, porque si aproximas cada elemento el resultado final puede distar mucho que si solo aproximas el resultado final. Esto te pasaba a ti cuando hacías $res+= number_format, que es lo mismo que decir $res=$res + number_format, lo cual NO es formatear el resultado final.

Comment: Vale, muchísimas gracias